# Javascripts output variable for Assetic Bundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

Here is my code:

```
{% block js %}
    {% javascripts filter='?yui_js' output='js/m/myfiles.js'
            '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/m/one.js'
            '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/m/two.js'
            '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/m/three.js'
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

I would like to be able to change my output value based on variable.

something like this:

```
{% set myOutput = 'js/m/myfiles_v2.js'%}
{% block js %}
    {% javascripts filter='?yui_js' output=myOutput
            '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/m/one.js'
            '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/m/two.js'
            '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/m/three.js'
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

But when I do that i get "Unexpected token "name" of value "myOutput" ("string" expected). Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why changing the name of the output file? I think it's not possible...

Comment: I want to add a suffix each time when deploy my project so that original file does not stay cached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create own assetic filter which will extends yui_js filter and overwrite function to create name.

Assetic filter is a service implements FilterInterface.

Here is sample definition of you filter as service:

```
<service id="my.if.filter" class="MyBundle\FilterClass">
    <tag name="assetic.filter" alias="my_alias" />
    <argument></argument>
    <argument>....</argument>
</service>
```

Here is a tutorial:

http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/05/24/symfony2-make-your-own-assetic-filter/